# Configure basic authentication with Spring Sleuth Zipkin

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I'm trying to configure my spring boot app to log into a zipkin server. The problem is that this server is protected by a proxy (with basic auth) and I cannot find any documentation describing how to configure authorization with spring-sleuth.

I have tried to use that kind of configuration :

```
spring.zipkin.baseUrl: http://user:password@zipkin-server:9411
```

But without success, logs indicating :

```
ZipkinRestTemplateWrapper    : Created POST request for "http://user:password@zipkin-server:9411/api/v2/spans"
ZipkinRestTemplateWrapper    : Setting request Accept header to [text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
ZipkinRestTemplateWrapper    : Writing [[B@46d92b65] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter@53804b23]
ZipkinRestTemplateWrapper    : POST request for "http://user:password@zipkin-server:9411/api/v2/spans" resulted in 401 (Unauthorized); invoking error handler
```

I have tried with curl and it works.

Has someone already succeed to configure authentication with spring-sleuth ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For basic authentication, the username and password are required to be sent as part of the HTTP Header `Authorization`. The header value is computed as Base64 encoding of the string `username:password`.So if the username is `abcd` and password is `1234`, the header will look something like this (Chatset used: UTF-8).

> Authorization: Basic YWJjZDoxMjM0

Sleuth cloud project provides `ZipkinRestTemplateCustomizer` to configure the `RestTemplate` used to communicate with the Zipkin server.

Refer to the documentation for the same: 
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/reference/html/#sending-spans-to-zipkin

Note: Base64 encoding is reversible and hence Basic auth credentials are not secured. HTTPS communication should be used along with Basic Authentication.